# Excel Sign-In Form when refreshing PivotTable

Tags: python, excel, windows, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have a pivot table conected to pbiazure. Once I click on the refresh I get every time Sign-In Form where I need to click on my name (button). How do I do that with python(selenium)? I need to perform this action while my screen is locked (Windows11) => interaction with GUI is not the way. I see that the excel file and the Form has the same PID. Thx
[image]